# Картинка с width: auto в абсолютно позиционированом блоке

Tags: css, css3, google-chrome

Итак, есть такая проблема:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
}
div img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/

если менять вертикальный размер окна в chromium браузерах (по крайней мере >43 версии)
то квадратную картинку внутри элемента будет плющить,

переключая высоту, после ресайза, можно добиться, чтобы ее со временем восстанавливало:

http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/1/

можно сделать так, чтобы картинку не плющило при ресайзе окна:

http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/2/

но проблема остается, если ресайзить родительский блок:

http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/3/

повторение проблемы у вас не гарантируется моя версия google-chrome:  43.0.2357.125 и текущая unstable (45.x)

Вопрос - есть ли нормальный способ решения ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А тебя наличие вертикального скролла ни капельки не смущает? И фикс-то один и тот же.

http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/6/
http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/7/

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
}

div img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
</div>
```

Comment: скролл нисколько не смущает, т.к. не в нем дело http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/8/ , про блок мне  на SO уже подсказали, я правда не считаю, что это правильное поведение браузера, несмотря на inline, т.к. другие работают нормально, да и при изменении высоты туда-обратно неправильно разную картинку рендерить.

Comment: нашел случай, где все равно глючит: http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/9/ причем хак с 200vh продолжает работать.

Comment: @eicto, что баг хрома - согласен. Что касается скролла и бага - причина-то одна и та же - элемент с особым поведением (которое ещё и не через css задаётся) ресайзится как inline-block. Ну не учли. Что касается flex'а, то у них с ним и похуже проблемы есть: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalmedia/s2Lpgojf/ - посмотри на hover в хроме и во всех остальных. А display:block в твоём варианте вообще игнорируется, потому что он во flex-контейнере. Что ты вообще пытаешься соорудить там?

Comment: @eicto, а вот так другой косяк - оно ресайзится, но обрезается: http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/10/ Зато вот так всё работает: http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/11/

Comment: Забавный баг, object-fit:contain на img - ещё один вариант.